# Java send email stuck with no exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Try to send an email using java. Find an example from: https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-in-html-format-using-javamail-api.

However, when try to send the email, it looks like the code stuck at `Transport.send(msg);` and doesn't make any progress anymore. And it also not timed out.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class HtmlEmailSender {

    public void sendHtmlEmail(String host, String port,
                              final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
                              String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        // set plain text message
        msg.setContent(message, "text/html");

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);
        log.info("Success!");

    }

    /**
     * Test the send html e-mail method
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // SMTP server information
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String port = "587";
        String mailFrom = "fromemail@gmail.com";
        String password = "password";

        // outgoing message information
        String mailTo = "toemail@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Hello my friend";

        // message contains HTML markups
        String message = "<i>Greetings!</i><br>";
        message += "<b>Wish you a nice day!</b><br>";
        message += "<font color=red>Duke</font>";

        HtmlEmailSender mailer = new HtmlEmailSender();

        try {
            mailer.sendHtmlEmail(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
                                 subject, message);
            System.out.println("Email sent.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to sent email.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to get rid of the initial issue by turning on the `IMAP` optional for my gmail account. But then I got another exception:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user='myusername', password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL true
Failed to sent email.
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2194)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:726)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at insbot.HtmlEmailSender.sendHtmlEmail(HtmlEmailSender.java:55)
    at insbot.HtmlEmailSender.main(HtmlEmailSender.java:83)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Do you see log messages in the console?

Comment: Haven't see any log message.

Comment: Are you sending on your local machine or in a server? Have you debugged to see which line is causing the issue?

Comment: By the way I removed the `gmail` tag since you are trying to send using `yahoo`, are you sure that is the correct host?

Comment: From my local machine (mac). I set a breakpoint at `Transport.send(msg)`, and when debugging, I choose `step into` using Intellij, and it stuck.

Comment: Autogoing connection blocked by firewall, maybe.

Comment: which version of javax mail jar are you using? I use mail-1.5.0-b01.jar with my gmail account and it just works fine (To address is same as from address).

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: @BillShannon I have updated turned in on and updated with the new exception.

Comment: Your new problem seems pretty obvious.  There is some reason you can't connect to the service at address `smtp.gmail.com` listening at port `587`.  I can connect to that port from my Mac, so you must have some sort of firewall thing going on, or some other reason that your workstation can't reach that port.  I'm pretty sure that `java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)` means that the connection never happened, so it doesn't matter what the code on your side is trying to do once connected.

Comment: A really good trick to have in your toolbox for things like this is 'telnet'.  See if you can connect via 'telnet' at a command prompt, by doing: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`.  Does this make a connection?  If not, then the problem has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @Steve yep, seems to be related with my company network. I try ssh to a AWS EC2 node and perform the command you mentioned and I got connected right away.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ (did you look at the entry right after the one I linked to?) has [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  It also tells you how to [connect through a proxy server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).

Comment: @chrisTina, so telnet doesn't work from your workstation, right?  If so, then I can't think of anything more to suggest.  You need to step away from your codeuynd just figure out what's going on with your network.  Can you get out in general...like to the main google site?  Are you working at a company that might be blocking certain outgoing connections?  That's often what this sort of thing is about.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation while sending email with null value for CC.